# Repository Base Log

Tags: c#, database, logging, radix

```
public void LogAdd(string processName, T item, List<T> items)
    {
        try
        {
            LogInfo entity = new LogInfo();
            entity.ProcessName = processName;
            if (item != null)
                entity.Data = new JsonSerializer().Serialize(item);
            else if(items.Count!=0)
                entity.Data = new JsonSerializer().Serialize(items);
            entity.CreateDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            Context.Set<LogInfo>().Add(entity);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    }
```

But `entity.Data = new JsonSerializer().Serialize(item);` throw an exception. Exception is:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module."

I want to make database table variable convert to json ? Or other solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize using Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

```
public void LogAdd(string processName, T item, List<T> items)
{
    try
    {
        LogInfo entity = new LogInfo();
        entity.ProcessName = processName;
        if (item != null)
            entity.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
        else if(items.Count!=0)
            entity.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
        entity.CreateDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        Context.Set<LogInfo>().Add(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {

    }
}
```